# gdb:given a address, can I find the allocated chunk containing it?

Tags: c, gdb

for example ,there is a allocated chunk 0x10000-0x20000 and I get the address 0x15000,can I get the chunk's info(start address, size and so on) by 0x15000?
Or can I get a allocated chunks list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb itself doesn't have any special knowledge of whatever allocators your program might be using.  So, there is no gdb command to get this information.

For glibc in particular, you can install the `gdb-heap` extension.  This is a set of Python scripts that add some commands to gdb for exploring the contents of the heap; it has knowledge of how the glibc `malloc` implementation works.

I couldn't readily find the canonical repository (Fedora Hosted seems to have vanished) but I did find a [fork on github](https://github.com/rogerhu/gdb-heap).  It's also packaged in some Linux distros; for example Fedora.